# ODataService Type Provider still exist?

Tags: f#, odata, type-providers

I'm looking now at F# Type Providers.

Particularity at [ODataService Type Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/odataservice-type-provider-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

This is a [snippet](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/odata.html), how to use it.

But looks like [fsharp.data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) doesn't have it anymore.

And when I try to use it, compiler gives me error:

[image]

So we don't have ODataService Type Provider anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FSharp.Data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) is a different project than [FSharp.Data.TypeProviders](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/). You need to be using the [FSharp.Data.TypeProviders](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders) NuGet package, and then it should work.